# Battery powered multi-camera outdoor home surveillance system where all video streams can be displayed on 1 screen

Tags: video, home-security, home-electronics

The key difference between this and a similar existing question is that I need my cameras to be not only wireless, but battery powered. I have one like this, the [Ring](https://ring.com/security-cams) "stickupcam", which is perfect except that it can only be displayed 1 camera at a time and only can be displayed on its mobile app.

I'm looking for the

- lowest cost
- battery powered
- wireless
- multi-camera
- outdoor

home surveillance system where *all video streams can be displayed on 1 screen*, such as a flat screen TV (either my normal home TV or a dedicated flat screen of some sort).

The idea is that I want to be able to see all parts of my yard at the same time to make sure that my dog is OK (there's a fence, but I still worry). My home is old, so there are no outdoor power outlets, few indoor ones, and I'm not eager to do major wiring upgrades to make this happen.